# The permalink for the page doesn't work and page's defined link throws "Object not found!"

Tags: permalinks, pages

I created new page in a fresh WordPress install. Version of WordPress is fairly new - 4.4.2. I set the permalink for the new page to be `http://localhost/gp/page-two/`‎.

Comment: You should provided more background: your settings for permalinks, `.htaccess` rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your permalinks in settings dubmenu item in wordpress's admin. Check so it is set properly and .htaccess is set properly. If it isn't try copy and paste the suggested content of it to the actual .htaccess file and try again.